# Migrating dockerized redis to another server

Tags: docker, redis, migrate

I am new to both docker and redis.  I have configured serverA to run redis inside docker.  The redis database has been pre-seeded with a thousand key/value pairs. I can confirm the data has been persisted in this container. I then created a new docker image from this container, uploaded it to my docker repository.

On serverB, I pulled the redis image "redis-preseeded" and got it started.  Using the redis-cli tool when I connect and issue the 'info keyspace' command, the keyspace is empty, suggesting none of the data made it across.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you use docker commit to make the new container?

Comment: Yes i used docker commit

Comment: Can you post your docker file? Or are you using a prebuilt one?

Comment: Using a prebuilt one, not using docker file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you is using the official image for Redis?

- https://hub.docker.com/_/redis/
- [Dockefile for the redis:3.2.0-alpine release](https://github.com/docker-library/redis/blob/6cb8a8015f126e2a7251c5d011b86b657e9febd6/3.2/alpine/Dockerfile#L32)

It has a volume declared:

```
..
VOLUME /data
WORKDIR /data
..
```

Volumes are described in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/). In a nutshell what the authors are doing is configuring Redis to store data on an external disk volume that will be maintained by the docker engine. Not only is this more efficient it also allows users to keep the data separate to the container using it.

Labouring the point a snapshot of the image will contain no data (if you think about it this is a good thing).

Once you understand these concepts then it becomes more obvious how data can be moved between servers:

- [Backup, Restore and Migrate data volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes)

Comment: Thanks Mark. Your explanation helped me understand how it works and I was able to successfully complete my task.  Also found this Export/Import .sh useful because it illustrates how to perform the operation step by step:  https://gist.github.com/alister/ed664cb51c21bc801e9a

Comment: @user3892260 A useful example script, I note it uses a data container, which would be the recommended pattern. Glad to help.